# CakePHP 1.3 alternative to SoftDeletable Behavior?

Tags: cakephp, behavior, soft-delete, recycle-bin

Does anyone know of an alternative to the **[SoftDeletable Behavior](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/mariano/2007/04/16/soft-delete-behavior)** that is compatible with **Cake 1.3.x**?

If there aren't any ready behaviors available, any suggestions on how I go about doing this in the latest Cake?

---

Figured out a quick hack. First and foremost, if your table introduce a **tinyint(1) unsigned** field named **deleted** which defaults to **0**.

In **app/app_model.php**, add in the following function:

```
function softDelete( $id ) {
    if( $id && $this->hasField( 'deleted' ) ) {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this->saveField( 'deleted', 1 );
    }

    return false;
}
```

and then from your controller's method (that performs the delete) call,

```
$this->Model->softDelete( $id );
```

Catch is, wherever you perform a **find()**, you need to specify the condition **deleted != 1**.

Still trying to figure out how to implement this in the same manner as the SoftDeletable behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i've adapted mariano's behavior to 1.3. look here - https://github.com/evilbloodydemon/cakephp-softdeletable2

Comment: Awesome dude :) Appreciate your effort.

Comment: Hello, I tried your code in my project - but it seems that the records are getting hard deleted instead of the 'deleted' field being set to 0. I included your code as it's supposed to be, i.e. as a behavior and set the 'field' to point to the 'deleted' field in my table. Still it keeps hard-deleting when I call the delete() method from the controller. Am I missing out on something here?

Comment: Never mind. A simple typo. I was using $actAs instead of $actsAs.

Answer (score 3):

Also worth noting: there is a [SoftDelete behavior](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/blob/master/models/behaviors/soft_delete.php) bundled in CakeDC's [Utils plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils).